# Connect to old version of MySQL 3.23 .NET c#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

There is no way to upgrade MySQL from 3.23
But I need to make an application with .NET C# to connect to this version of MySQL

I downloaded Connector/Net from mysql official site, but I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in MySql.Data.dll Additional information: Connector/Net no longer
>   supports server versions prior to 5.0

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use error Connector/Net to MySQL, you should download lower version Connector/Net to get it work.